# I have an issue with MUI Toolpad

Tags: toolpad

hello i use mui toolpad https://mui.com/toolpad/
but i face an issue: when i create container and preview it i found that the container don't have the max width or full size of page and while i inspect the page i found that there is container with max-width: 1200px; surround my component and i don't have any control to this container

i need to remove this maxwidth from the container to make my container take full size

Comment: Could you open an issue on https://github.com/mui/mui-toolpad? Thanks